# how to do the dim reduction for the tensor samples (vector feature)

Tags: machine-learning

How to do the dim reduction (like PCA) for the `vector feature`? We can assume that each sample has 3 features $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and the dimension of features is 2/3/4 respectively:

$$x = (x_1,x_2,x_3) = \Big(\big(x_1^1,x_1^2\big), \big(x_2^1,x_2^2,x_2^3\big),\big(x_3^1,x_3^2,x_3^3,x_3^4\big),\Big),$$

with the label $y.$ We want to train a  learner to use $x$ to predict label $y.$

Now I want to reduce the dim of $x$ into 2, which can be either:

1. Features selection: remove some features, e.g. $X^* = (x_1,x_2).$
2. Features extraction (like PCA, LDA) e.g. $X^* = (\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2).$ Here $\hat{x}_i$ can have any dim and is obtained from $x_1,x_2,x_3$ (refer PCA).

Actually I am more interested in the 2. Features extraction.

Moreover, for any tensor samples, usually how do we take the dim reduction? Or could you refer some references?

Comment: Please edit your original question.  This version currently makes as little sense as that, which is why offering an example could really help.

Comment: @whuber sorry my original question has been closed, I don't how to unlock it. That's why I open a new one.

Comment: @whuber could you answer my original question?

Comment: I can't, because I can't figure out what you're trying to ask.